# How can I add a css class to an existing Woocommerce/Wordpress widget

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to add a pair of classes to the Woocommerce Product Categories Widget. In order to ensure I don't break any updates, I'd like to do so without editing the original source code, or having to create a new replacement widget.

From what I've gathered, `widget_display_callback` should be able to do what I need, but the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/widget_display_callback) is really sparse (actually non-existant). So I'm not really certain how to pull the setting that contains the css classnames that are applied to the widget.

My current code is below, which is obviously not working. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

```
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', 'add_classes', 10, 3 );

function add_classes($settings, $widget, $args) {
    if (get_class($widget) == 'WC_Widget_Product_Categories') {
        $widget_ops['classname'] .= " hidden-phone hidden-tablet";
    }
    return $widget_ops;
}
```

Here's what I think is the relevant code snippet in the `class-wc-widget-product-categories.php` file:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

class WC_Widget_Product_Categories extends WP_Widget {

var $woo_widget_cssclass;
var $woo_widget_description;
var $woo_widget_idbase;
var $woo_widget_name;
var $cat_ancestors;
var $current_cat;

/**
 * constructor
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
function WC_Widget_Product_Categories() {

    /* Widget variable settings. */
    $this->woo_widget_cssclass = 'woocommerce widget_product_categories';
    $this->woo_widget_description = __( 'A list or dropdown of product categories.', 'woocommerce' );
    $this->woo_widget_idbase = 'woocommerce_product_categories';
    $this->woo_widget_name = __( 'WooCommerce Product Categories', 'woocommerce' );

    /* Widget settings. */
    $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => $this->woo_widget_cssclass, 'description' => $this->woo_widget_description );

    /* Create the widget. */
    $this->WP_Widget('product_categories', $this->woo_widget_name, $widget_ops);
}
```

Comment: the filter `widget_display_callback` returns the `$settings` variable. so you can do it with this filter. I too didnt find any way to do that, YET :D

Comment: this might be helpful i guess : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351603/wordpress-add-config-option-to-all-widget-settings

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
function changeclass() {
    WC_Widget_Product_Categories->woo_widget_cssclass= 'whatever';
}

add_action('init', 'changeclass');
```

if it doesn't work you will need to investigate a bit more, where does the code above get hooked to? (its a class so it will be add_action('init' array($this, 'functionname');  (prob WP_WIDGET function.

see possible hooks here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in /home1/treasure/public_html/cabinet/wp-content/themes/best/functions.php on line 43" error.

Comment: sorry replace  WC_Widget_Product_Categories with the active object search for new WC_Widget_Product_Categories in the code or if its a static object WC_Widget_Product_Categories::woo_widget_cssclass etc unfortunately i cant see this!